# Oreo on Fleish dishes

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

I'm looking for primary sources that discuss the rules about dairy equipment food (such as oreo) being used on meat dishes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem putting pareve food cooked in clean meat/dairy-equipment on opposite gendered dishes. ([Rama YD 95:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%94_%D7%91))

Comment: I was under the impression that Ashkenazim consider dairy equipment (but otherwise pareve) food to be dairy.

Comment: @ShamanSTK I'm just reporting what the Rama holds. That said, I believe this Rama is pretty commonly accepted in Ashkenazic circles.